# VBA - Match range to see if cell value is in array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

ISOmatch contains all the values that are in the arrays sISO and sISOnew. I am looking to copy values from approximately 200 different workbooks int one file. ISOmnatch is a column of all the ISO codes in the arrays.

I am trying to have it cycle through each book, copy a value, find the ISO match and paste that value, then move to the next book, find the iso match, etc.

Here is the code I have worked up so far. The main issue I am hacing is how to detect if there is a match or not such as "If cell.value = sISO() or sISOnew() Then". I am not too sure how to implement the embedded excel match function or if that would even be easier.

```
    Sub NTSDM_Econ()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim isoWF, isoNWF As String
Dim sISO As Variant
Dim sISOnew As Variant

isoWF = "J:\Washington\Groups\CIG\GRS\Workfiles\"
isoNWF = "J:\Washington\Groups\CIG\GRS\Workfiles\New Countries\"

sISO = Array( _
"AFG", "AGO", "ALB", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", "BEL", "BFA", "BGD", _
"BGR", "BHR", "BIH", "BLR", "BOL", "BRA", "BTN", "BWA", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", _
"CIV", "CMR", "COG", "COL", "CRI", "CUB", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DNK", "DOM", "DRC", "DZA", _
"ECU", "EGY", "ESP", "EST", "FIN", "FRA", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", "GHA", "GIN", "GNQ", "GRC", _
"GTM", "HKG", "HND", "HRV", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", "ISL", "ISR", "ITA", _
"JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", "KGZ", "KHM", "KOR", "KOS", "KWT", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", "LBY", _
"LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LVA", "MAR", "MDA", "MDG", "MEX", "MKD", "MLI", "MMR", "MNE", "MNG", _
"MOZ", "MRT", "MUS", "MWI", "MYS", "NAM", "NCL", "NER", "NGA", "NIC", "NLD", "NOR", "NPL", _
"NZL", "OMN", "PAK", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "PNG", "POL", "PRI", "PRT", "PRY", "QAT", "ROM", _
"RUS", "SAU", "SDN", "SEN", "SGP", "SLE", "SLV", "SRB", "SSD", "SVK", "SVN", _
"SWE", "SWZ", "SYR", "TGO", "THA", "TJK", "TKM", "TLS", "TTO", "TUN", "TUR", "TWN", "TZA", _
"UGA", "UKR", "URY", "USA", "UZB", "VEN", "VNM", "YEM", "ZAF", "ZMB", "ZWE")

sISOnew = Array( _
"ABW", "AIA", "AND", "ASM", "ATG", "BEN", "BHS", "BLZ", "BMU", "BRB", "BRN", "CAF", "COM", _
"CPV", "CUW", "CYM", "DJI", "DMA", "ERI", "ETH", "FJI", "FSM", "GMB", "GNB", "GRD", "GUF", _
"GUM", "GUY", "HTI", "JAM", "KIR", "KNA", "LCA", "LIE", "LUX", "MAC", "MCO", "MDV", "MHL", _
"MLT", "MTQ", "NRU", "PLW", "PRK", "PSE", "REU", "RWA", "SLB", "SMR", "SOM", "STP", "SUR", _
"SXM", "SYC", "SYC", "TCD", "TON", "TUV", "VCT", "VIR", "VUT", "WSM")

' smaller array used to test
sISO = Array("AFG", "AGO")

For Each ctry In sISO
    For Each Cell In Range("B4:B214")
        If UBound(Filter(sISO, Cell.Value)) > -1 Then

            '' do some stuff

            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Next
Next ctry

End Sub
```

Comment: How should the final data be displayed?

Comment: I'm slightly confused what you're doing in your last lines of code (the double for loop) - Could you explain a bit more of what you're trying to actually have accomplished there??

Comment: Overall, I'm seeing a few issues with your code, could you make a more bullet-point idea of what you'd like the code to actually do - Kind of pseudo-code it?

Comment: Each value in the array is also an individual excel file, i.e. "AFG.xlsx". The first for loop opens one of the approx. 200 files, copies the data, then I am trying to match the string value in the array (AFG) to that value in a range (B2:B214 that have all the same values as the array). This will then be done for 12 columns going across for each value in the array. Then, move on to the next country in a separate workbook(i.e. "AGO") and apply the same steps. This is what the double for loop is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if an item is in an array with Filter(). Instead of `If cell.value = sISO() or sISONew()` something like  `if UBound(Filter(sISO, cell.value)) > -1 or UBound(Filter(sISONew, cell.value)) > -1 then ...` should work.

Comment: This does work in that it will populate the necessary cells...yet for the nested for-next loop I have, it will overwrite each row for each item in the Array. Is there any way to force it to stop after finding the first match? I will update my post with the new code.

Comment: Your outer for loop seems unnecessary. Why loop through the array, element by element, and then test if ANY array element is in the cell you are analyzing. Either keep the two For loops and change your `if` statement to `IF ctry = cell.value then` (meaning you have a match) or dump the outer for loop and use `filter` which will tell you that your cell.value is in the array.

Comment: That works! I was making things much more complicated than necessary. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function InStr() to see if the values match, but you then need to have all your values in a string. Here is the part of the code that could do that. Just make sure you fill the array before you enter the loops

```
Dim ISOlist As String
Dim i As Long
Dim myVal As String

'Fill the two arrays into one long string with comma-separated values.
'The string need to make sure there is a comma both before and after each value
For i = LBound(sISO) To UBound(sISO)
    ISOlist = ISOlist & "," & sISO(i)
Next
For i = LBound(sISOnew) To UBound(sISOnew)
    ISOlist = ISOlist & "," & sISOnew(i)
Next
ISOlist = ISOlist & ","        'the ending comma is important

        'Get the value that I should test, adding a comma before and after
        myVal = "," & cell.value & ","

        'If cell.Value = sISO() Or sISOnew() Then
        If InStr(myVal, ISOlist) > 0 Then
```